# How to adjust position of drop-down block in Nice-Menu?

Tags: 6, routes, navigation

I have inherited a site built in Drupal 6 that uses Nice-Menus for both the top and side nav bars.  I've been tasked with modifying the current navigation and have run into issues adjusting both the position and width of various menu items.

You can see the issue by going to http://neoninc.org and hovering over "ABOUT" in the top nav bar, then "About NEON & Mission >>."  You should see that the menu item for "Governance" doesn't align properly with its parent item.

The previous developer added the following items to the CSS page called by nice-menu to adjust their widths:

```
ul.nice-menu li.menu-563 li { width: 20em; !important}   /*  ABOUT */
ul.nice-menu li.menu-840 li { width: 20em; !important}   /* CONTACT US */
ul.nice-menu li.menu-236 li { width: 24em; !important }  /* SCIENCE */
ul.nice-menu li.menu-4191 li { width: 20em; !important } /* CITIZEN SCIENCE */
```

I tried adding the following:

```
ul.nice-menu li.menu-781 li { margin-left: 16px; !important} /*  ABOUT >> Governance */
```

and then:

```
ul.nice-menu li.menu-781 li { left: 16px; !important} /*  ABOUT >> Governance */
```

both of which seem to work when editing the CSS directly in FireBug.  They don't work when inserted into the actual CSS file, and I'm stumped.

Yes, I've rebooted, cleared the local cache, cleared all caches in drupal, and double-checked that I actually uploaded the edited CSS file.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be overriding this...

```
ul.nice-menu-down li ul li ul, #header-region ul.nice-menu-down li ul li ul
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!  That worked just a little too well by moving more than just the menu-781 item.  Please take a look under "News Center | Events >>" to see what I mean.  How can I limit this to just the one?  I've tried "li.menu-781" in place of both "li" to no avail.

Comment: I wouldnt recommend doing it just to a single item but it would be the above with li.menu-781 so... #header-region ul.nice-menu-down li ul li ul li.menu-781

Comment: Thanks, @Alex!  With a bit more tweaking, this solved the issue.